# ASP.net Website DataBind to SQL server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web

I've been working on this site on VS Studio for Web 2012. Most of it is HTML and ASP, but I've included a DayPilot calendar that I downloaded from SourceForge. I, apparently, must DataBind the calendar to my SQL server, so that users can login and set aside times for themselves on the calendar.  I've used just about every recommended code I can find on the Net, but none seem to work on the Calendar page.
Here is the aspx page and the aspx.vb page codes:
(aspx page)

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"   AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="calendarpg.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

    <%@ Register Assembly="DayPilot" Namespace="DayPilot.Web.Ui" TagPrefix="DayPilot" %>

   <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/DayPilot/calendar.js")%>">         
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
            .auto-style8 {
            font-size: large;
        }
    </style>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Themes/themes.css")%>" />
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    dbo.BasicData
    <DayPilot:DayPilotNavigator ID="DayPilotNavigator1" runat="server" />
    <DayPilot:DayPilotCalendar ID="DayPilotCalendar1" runat="server" Days="7" EventMoveJavaScript="alert('eventMove(e.start(), newEnd')" BackColor="#CCFFFF" DataStartField="null"></DayPilot:DayPilotCalendar>
    <DayPilot:DayPilotScheduler ID="DayPilotScheduler1" runat="server">     
    </DayPilot:DayPilotScheduler>
    <br />
    <h1><strong>Scheduling</strong></h1>
    <span class="auto-style8">Requests are made via the Calendar for each of the respective Sandboxes. 
    A minimum of 24-hour notice is rquired when making a request to allow
    time for preparation of a Sandbox, 
    <br />
    time zone differences, and to resolve any
    scheduling conflicts.
    <br />
    <br />
    The process for booking is similar to booking a conference room.
    <br />
    <br />
    Choose a day and time that is open, for the Sandbox you're interested in using,
    then choose the open hours that work best for your schedule. </span>
    </asp:Content>
```

(aspx.vb page)

```
Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
'Declaration
Public Event DataBinding As EventHandler

Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
DayPilotCalendar1.DataSource = getData()
DataBind()
End Sub

Public Function getData() As Data.DataTable
Dim dt As Data.DataTable
dt = New Data.DataTable

dt.Columns.Add("start", GetType(DateTime))
dt.Columns.Add("end", GetType(DateTime))
dt.Columns.Add("name", GetType(String))
dt.Columns.Add("id", GetType(String))

Dim dr As Data.DataRow = dt.NewRow()
dr("id") = 0
dr("start") = Convert.ToDateTime("15:50")
dr("end") = Convert.ToDateTime("15:55")
dr("name") = "Event 1"
dt.Rows.Add(dr)

dr = dt.NewRow()
dr("id") = 1
dr("start") = Convert.ToDateTime("16:00")
dr("end") = Convert.ToDateTime("17:00")
dr("name") = "Event 2"
dt.Rows.Add(dr)

dr = dt.NewRow()
dr("id") = 2
dr("start") = Convert.ToDateTime("16:15")
dr("end") = Convert.ToDateTime("18:45")
dr("name") = "Event 3"
dt.Rows.Add(dr)

Return dt
End Function
End Class
```

(this is my Web.Config page as it stands now)

```
    <using System.Web.Configuration;  />
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
    <configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnStringDb1" connectionString="DataSource=Win08-SDBX1\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualC, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Adapter.v9.0, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.DesignTime.v9.0, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting.v9.0, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ProgrammingModel, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v9.0, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"  namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
     </pages>
    </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

If any of that makes sense, or you see where I'm going wrong, please share or correct my coding.  Thank you!

Comment: first thing i see, time is set to 24H format... could that be an issue

Comment: I should add, when I run the site on the test server, the aspx.vb page for the Calendar has a problem with the DataBind() control code. I keep getting the message:
"NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code"

Comment: If you dont bind the calendar control to anything, does it show on the test server at all ?

Comment: You say the error comes from the `DataBind` function, but you have not shown that function.  I see where it's called in Page_Load.

Comment: Yes, if there isn't any db connection coded in, then the calendar page loads with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
DayPilotCalendar1.DataSource = getData()
DataBind()
End Sub

This need to be 

Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
DayPilotCalendar1.DataSource = getData()
DayPilotCalendar1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the Databind function that is called by PageLoad?

I had an issue similar to this when I was working on a C# asp.net application. I created a method to bind the data from a dataset that contained a table of cards. When loading the table "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code" was thrown and upon looking at the table I could see that a null value was being held.

When you are debugging and the exception is thrown, what is being shown as the held value of the data table?

If it is null then your table is not referring to an object.